# Getting the list of schema objects corresponding to a service using Apache Olingo

Tags: apache, odata, olingo

I am trying to read the metadata from an OData Endpoint using Apache Olingo library.
I want to get the list of Schemas that are there in the service.

Sample code goes like this-

```
 DataServices services; //TODO:
 for (Schema schema : services.getSchemas()){}
```

How do I intialize this 'services' variable?

Answer (score 0):

1. Fire an HTTP request to the OData endpoint and get the response as
   an Input Stream.
2. call the Olingo API - `EntityProvider.readMetadata(content, false);` where content -
   InputStream and second param tell whether the lib should validate
   the metadata.
3. The Olingo API in step 2 returns an Edm object that can be used to get the elements of Edm.

However I dont see a method in Edm that can give schema information. You could always raise a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO for missing features or bugs.

Refer - http://olingo.apache.org/doc/tutorials/OlingoV2BasicClientSample.html for some more details.

Regards
Chandan